# How to change all the ethereum blocks from C drive to D drive -- question about the answer

Tags: blocks

I'm new here and have no idea if this is the right way to respond. So I duplicated the question a have a question about:

I've done the things written in the answer on the original question and I could see the text file. But the blocks start sync from scratch on the old location (C:Drive). 
What could be the reason?
Hope you can shine some light on this.
Ite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, in the middle of sync I just noticed that i was running out of space, and desired that now I want to use another drive: not `C:\data_directory`, but `D:\data_directory`. So I've closed geth, then copied data, as you exactly asked "from C: drive to D: drive", and run following command:

`C:\geth\bin\geth.exe --datadir "D:\data_directory" --keystore "E:\keystoredir" --nousb --syncmode "fast" --cache=16384`

And that standed for:

- geth binary from `C:` drive: `C:\geth\bin\geth.exe` ,
- store or use blockchain stored in `D:\data_directory`
- store and use wallet keys in `E:\keystoredir`
- usb hardware wallets are disabled (have none by hand, no need for support it)
- 16 gigabytes of ram are dedicaded to geth (75% for sync by default) assuming you have 24 or 32 and more gb RAM
- mode is "fast" (on older sata2 ssd and core i7 920 from 2010s you will sync in 3-4 days from scratch: as for today there are [263+ millions of known state entries](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14647) (importing stage)

I am fully synced now and my SSD `D:\data_directory` usage is 152+ GB

---

To attach to that node for console you should run like:

`C:\geth\bin\geth.exe attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`

Then in second console window you will be able to type commands.

---

PS. Voteup if you found that info useful! Btw, what was your old question?